# R - string - split and join

Tags: r, string

I try to write skript. I have ip adress and time. From ip adress I want to create 3 numbers and from time I want just hours and minutes. Example : 158.188.10.251 and result : 158,158188,15818810 . I have this code :

```
data = matrix( 
  c("158.188.10.251","15/Oct/2017:14:06:29 +0200",
    "207.46.13.6","15/Oct/2017:14:35:55 +0200",
    "157.55.39.32","15/Oct/2017:23:43:49 +0200"
  ), 

  nrow=3,             
  ncol=2,              
  byrow = TRUE)  

newdata <- matrix(, nrow = 3, ncol = 5)
for (i in 1:3){
#split first item to colums
a <- strsplit(data[i,1], ".", fixed = TRUE)
#create 
a2 <- paste(a[1],a[2],sep="")
a3 <- paste(a2,a[3],sep="")

#from string to int
newdata[i, 1]<-strtoi(a[1], base = 0L)
newdata[i, 2]<-strtoi(a2, base = 0L)
newdata[i, 3]<-strtoi(a3, base = 0L)

#choose hourse and minute from time  
c <- substr(data[i,2], 13, 14)
newdata[i, 4]<- strtoi(c, base = 0L)
d <- substr(data[i,2], 16, 17)
newdata[i, 5]<- strtoi(d, base = 0L)

}
```

Problem is that newdata look like :

```
> print (newdata)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   14    6
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   14   35
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   23   43
```

And value a is a list with 4 chars

```
[[1]]
[1] "157" "55"  "39"  "32"
```

but when I try print just one this chars :

```
> print (a[1,1])
Error in a[1, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
> print (a[1,])
Error in a[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
> print (a[,1])
Error in a[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
data = matrix( 
  c("158.188.10.251","15/Oct/2017:14:06:29 +0200",
    "207.46.13.6","15/Oct/2017:14:35:55 +0200",
    "157.55.39.32","15/Oct/2017:23:43:49 +0200"
  ), 

  nrow=3,             
  ncol=2,              
  byrow = TRUE)  

ips <- matrix("",ncol=3,nrow=nrow(data))
times <- matrix("",ncol=2,nrow=nrow(data))

for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  tip <- unlist(strsplit(data[i,1],"\\."))
  ttime <- unlist(strsplit(data[i,2],":"))
  ips[i,1] <- tip[1]
  ips[i,2] <- paste0(tip[1:2],collapse="")
  ips[i,3] <- paste0(tip[1:3],collapse="")
  times[i,1] <- ttime[2]
  times[i,2] <- ttime[3]
}

ips
times
```